# Respberry Pi fails to boot with custom kernel

Tags: kernel, cross-compilation, ubuntu

I'm trying to cross compile my kernel with touchscreen enabled, however my Respberry Pi fails to boot with the custom kernel.
I was trying to compile the kernel on my ubuntu 10.4 (x64) with different config files but after transferring the files to my Pi I was no longer able to boot it.

These were the steps I followed as per various descriptions:

```
apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi make ncurses-dev ia32-libs
```

Then I downloaded the kernel source [rpi-3.10.y](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/archive/rpi-3.10.y.tar.gz) and the [tools](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools)

```
export KERNEL_SRC=/home/marco/kernel/linux-rpi-3.10.19
export CCPREFIX=/home/marco/kernel/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi- 
export MODULES_TEMP=/home/marco/kernel/modules/
```

Get .config file from the running raspberry and transfer to the ubuntu machine

```
zcat /proc/config.gz > myconfigfromrpi.config
```

In the kernel source folder

```
make mrproper
cp ../myconfigfromrpi.config ./.config
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX} oldconfig 
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX} menuconfig
```

Using editor I changed the line to be "CONFIG_LOCALVERSION"="+MW" and continue

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX}
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX} INSTALL_MOD_PATH=${MODULES_TEMP}
modules_install
```

In the folder /tools/mkimage

```
./imagetool-uncompressed.py ${KERNEL_SRC}/arch/arm/boot/Image
```

The I transfer the new kernel as `kernel_new.img` to Respberry into folder `/boot/` and update the `config.txt` accordingly.

Transfer content of folder `/lib/firmware/` to Respberry into folder `/lib/firmware/`
Transfer folder `/lib/firmware/modules/3.10.19+mw` to Respberry into folder `/lib/modules/`

Did I miss something or do I something wrong?

Comment: I'm wondering, this seems like a rather interesting question, did goldilocks' answer resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This:

> `> apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi`

Will be a toolchain targeting the more common ARMv7 architecture.  It probably does not properly support the ARMv6 Broadcom SoC used on the pi, but you could try by adding:

```
CCFLAGS += -mcpu=armv6j -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard
```